# Learning curve - Why does the train learning curve is flat?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, overfitting

I implemented a model in which I use Random Forest as classifier and I wanted to plot the learning curves for both training and test sets to decide what to do next in order to improve my model.

**Dataset details:**

107 radiomics feature extracted from 580 CT image.

The training dataset has 406 records.

The testing dataset has 174 records.

**The Code:**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[df.columns.difference(['label'])], 
                                                df['label'], 
                                                test_size=0.3, 
                                                random_state=42)

over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='auto')   #OverSampling Minority class
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
steps = [('over', over), ('model', clf)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, pipeline,scoring='precision')
plt.show()
```

**My results are in the below image**
[image: Learning Curves]

I wonder why does the training Curve always flat? (Also other training metrics Curve are flat)

Is my model overfits?

Comment: You’ve identified the problem already by adding the overfitting tag. What else is there to say?

Comment: Tune the model’s hyper parameters. Experiment with removing smote.

Comment: Any idea how can i fix this problem or what is the source of overfitting? As you can see in my code i tried resampling but nothing changed.

Comment: I think the linked post answers the question, but just to clear up any confusion — what do you think the definition of overfitting is? Based on that definition, are there any changes to the random forest classifier (look up the scikit-learn docs if you need) that you hypothesize might help?